# Evaluating an improper integral involving natural logarithm

Tags: logarithms, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to evaluate the following integral

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\log(t^2-a^2)}{(b^2+t^2)^2}dt$$
with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

I know that similar integrals do appear in other posts but somehow I am stuck and can not see how to evaluate this. If I try to use contour integration methods, should I make a branch cut between $-a$ and $a$ and close the contour in the upper half plane ? Or is there another method without using residue calculus ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when $|t| < a$ ? Have you chosen a branch or have you excluded that with a $\log|t^2-a^2|$ instead?

Comment: Why you are closing this question ? I was just curious about improper integrals involving logarithm. How this question do violate any rules ?